Gave up waiting for the root file system device - initramfs error - What is the fix?
After what appeared to be a successful install of Linux, I got this error on trying to boot up.
Gave up waiting for the root file system device.
Common Problems:
Boot Args ( cat /proc/cmdline )
Check rootdelay=( did the system wait long enough )
Missing Modules ( cat/proc/modules; ls /dev )
UUID = XXXXXXXX - XXXX - XXXX - XXXX - XXXXXXXXXXXX does not exit

// verfied this matches and is the UUID above
c00a3975-a1f2-4f8f-b390-a209c6b3aabe ( per gparted ) /dev/sdb5, ext4

The part I find strange is that running Ubuntu 22.04 live off my USB stick works fine.  But when I install it and try to run it I get this error.
initramfs appears to to be able to detect my SSD.  Which is also strange because in the live version I see plain as day in Gparted and was even able to verify that inintramfs had the correct UUID.
I see some shot in the dark solutions like changing the rootdelay variable, adding possible missing modules for NVMe which is the type of SSD drive I have, and  other shots in the dark like reinstalling initramfs, resinstalling grub.
I have already made sure that Windows in not encrypting the drive - I turned off bitlocker, I turned off TPM, I turned off fast boot.  These were other shots in the dark I found off the internet.
My question is as follows:  What is a good troubleshooting approach to solve this?  What is the next step in this approach.
My approach has been to try the simple things first like turning off bitlocker, etc.  Now it seems the problem needs a more technical fix.
What boggles my mind, is I thought the main purpose of running a live version before installing was to make sure things work.  It works live but the actual install to my SSD does not work.
The closest solution I found was this post here but this was for UFS drives and I have NVMe.
